# List form customized in powerapps is not being displayed correctly on the SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps-forms

I have customized a list form in PowerApps and published it to SharePoint. Although the form is being published, only half of it is visible when I click on the "New Item" tab in the list. Is there any way the full form can be published? What changes do I have to make in PowerApps?

[image]

Comment: Any screenshots to give a better idea of how it looks like? Because I'm not really sure to understand your problem

Comment: I've added an image, please take a look at it.

Comment: At first sight I would say you gave the form a wider format than it should be. Maybe you have to go back over your steps. And yeah, try give more info because right now we're just guessing

Answer (score 0):

Please publish the form again to check the result:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/customize-list-form#save-and-publish-the-form

If the issue still exists, please provide more information about how did you customize the form.